# How can I make part of my label not connected to its input?

Tags: html, css, input, label

I have a basic input and label: https://codepen.io/agrawalishaan/pen/QWBxBdK

```
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
<label for="myInput">
  I am a label! <span>icon</span>
</label>
<input id="myInput"/>
```

When I click on the label, the cursor is set inside the input, which is desirable.

My label also contains an info icon. When I hover over that icon, a popup appears (so I need `hover` to work).

On mobile, there is no hover, it requires a tap instead. But when I tap on this icon, both the popup appears and the input is selected, how can I disable the input selection specifically when clicking only on the icon?

Answer (score 0):

I have added some javascript that uses the event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the input is not focused when clicking the icon.

```js
const infoIcon = document.querySelector('.info-icon');
const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');

infoIcon.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of focusing on the input
  
//toggles the popup on click/touch of the icon
popup.style.display = popup.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none' 
});
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#popup {
   position:absolute;
   display:none;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border-style:solid;
   background-color:yellow;
}

.info-icon:hover + #popup { /*uses the '+' adjacent child selector to display popup on hover*/
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="myInput">
  I am a label! <span class="info-icon">icon</span>
  <div id='popup'>POP UP</div>
</label>
<input id="myInput"/>
```